# DetailsView not updating and changing only after 2 clicks, Cancel not showing editable values in readonly

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, data-binding, detailsview

I created a detailsview which appears after a date is selected in a calender. This detailsview is filled via a select statement in code behind. Here is a list of my problems i encouter:

1. I have to click twice on the edit button to get the detailsview in Edit mode.
2. Once in edit mode i see the update and cancel button, but I also have to click twice on cancel to get back to the read only state.
3. When I'm in Edit mode i have 3 rows which can be editted, when I press cancel twice in readOnly mode the values of these 3 rows aren't shown anymore, they're just empty fields although the data is still in the database.
4. When I change something in Edit mode and press Update, my detailsview just dissapears.

Code-behind:

```
protected void DetailView1_ModeChanging(Object sender, DetailsViewModeEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewMode == DetailsViewMode.Edit)
    {
        DetailsView1.ChangeMode(e.NewMode);
    }
    if (e.CancelingEdit)
    {
        DetailsView1.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.ReadOnly);   
    }
}

protected void DetailView1_ItemUpdating(Object sender, DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    DetailsView1.DataBind();
}

protected void DetailsView1_ItemUpdated(object sender, DetailsViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    DetailsView1.DataBind();
}
```

Markup:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" 
    OnModeChanging="DetailView1_ModeChanging" OnItemUpdating="DetailView1_ItemUpdating"
    OnItemUpdated="DetailsView1_ItemUpdated"
    AllowPaging="True" PageSize="5" HeaderText="Agenda"  CellPadding="10" 
    ForeColor="#333333" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in `DetailView1_ModeChanging`

> The ModeChanging event is raised when a DetailsView control attempts to change between edit, insert, and read-only mode, but before the CurrentMode property is updated. This allows you to provide an event handler that performs a custom routine, such as canceling the mode change, whenever this event occurs.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.modechanging.aspx)

you need to use `Item Command event`

```
protected void DetailsView1_ItemCommand(object sender, DetailsViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
    {
        DetailsView1.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.Edit);
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

```
 protected void DetailView1_ModeChanging(Object sender, DetailsViewModeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewMode == DetailsViewMode.Edit)
        {
            DetailsView1.ChangeMode(e.NewMode);
            DetailsView1.Datebind(); // add this and check
        }
        if (e.CancelingEdit)
        {
            DetailsView1.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.ReadOnly);   
            DetailsView1.Datebind(); // add this and check
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. I added `OnItemCommand="DetailsView1_ItemCommand` to my detailsview and used the code you wrote down above. At first I put all my code in text, then I got the message it was firing the ModeChanging event which wasn't handled so I put that method back as code to use. The problem remains, I still have to click twice before I go to Edit mode and Editing doesn't work.

Comment: I have tried this and when I run the program my detailsview dissapears from the screen when I press the Edit button. The same problem occurs when I use a gridview instead of detailsview.